# Ubuntu 16.04 booting into initramfs screen

Tags: initramfs

I tried the `exit` command, and here is the whole screen content:

```
BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)exit
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problem:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
ALERT! UUID=e1df100f-2ef0-447d-94ad-2b4275e1e875 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4) built-in shell (ash)
    Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

---

I even tried booting from live USB but I get a message:

**Exception Encountered**
Unable to find and canditiate hard disks to install to.

Please can anyone help me in restoring my system?

Comment: I never used that shell, but if you type ls, it should list the partitions.

Comment: Something on the boot device is broken: look for boot device in `dmesg | grep sd[a-d]` and post the result

Comment: BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)ls
dev var lib sbin etc usr lib64 proc
root init scripts run conf bin sys tmp
(initramfs)                                                                                                         @davidbaumann

Comment: Nothing happens when I execute this command:        
(initramfs)dmesg  | grep sd[a-d]
(initramfs)                                                                                                                                                                                                     @Simon Sudler

Comment: @JThakur, okay, the kernel did not find any hard disk in your system. Are you sure, that the disk is present? Boot with a Live-CD/USB and check if the device is present

Comment: @Simon Sudler , My system was working fine few days ago and suddenly this problem cropped up recently. I'm positive that nothing changed on the hardware/disk front. When I tried booting with USB it didn't go through and it showed a message: Exception encountered - Unable to find and candidate hard disks to install to.                                Thanks!

Comment: @JThakur This points all to a missing/defect hard disk. Open the box, check the hard disk cables, replace the hard disk and boot again with the USB.

Answer (score 0):

The following BIOS settings for Dell Ubuntu system resolves the issue:

General Section > Boot Sequence > UEFI

System Configuration Section > SATA Operation > AHCH

Secure Boot Section > Secure Boot Enable > Disabled